# Inserir option no select multiple dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp

Bom Dia!!!

Preciso que ao digitar um número do processo e clicar na lupa, o processo vá pra caixa do select multiple, conforme imagem em anexo. Porém preciso esse processo várias vezes e ir populando o select multiple e depois clicar no botão selecionar e esses valores selecionados apareçam numa caixa de texto na tela principal, pois essa caixinha é um modal.
Hj só consigo inserir um processo, se eu procurar por outro processo e clicar na lupa, ele substitui o que já está na caixa, ao invés de acrescentar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Grata.

Comment: E qual a forma que você está usando para adicionar o processo ao `select`?

Comment: Posta o código que vc está usando para setar o select

Answer (score 0):

Podemos colocar um código que adicionará os valores do `input` no `select` ao clicar na lupa, e posteriormente fazer algo com o conteúdo. O código fica assim:

```js
$("#vai").click(function() {
  var processo_val = $("#processo").val();
  $("#select").append(
    $("<option/>")
    .val(processo_val)
    .text(processo_val)
  );
  $("#processo").val("").focus();
});

$("#ok").click(function() {
  var processos = [];
  $("#select option").each(function(idx, el) {
    processos.push($(el).val());
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(processos));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Processo:</strong> <input id="processo" type="text"> <button id="vai">adicionar!</button><br><br>
<select id="select" multiple style="width: 200px;">
</select>

<hr>

<button id="ok" style="font-size:16pt;">Clique aqui para fazer algo com os processos!</button>
```